# Sub query alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a report that based on 2 date ranges I know how to handle the first date range but not the second one. A sub query wont work because it can only return a single variable so I'm not sure how to get the second range of dates.

```
select fccompany,fcustno,ftotprice,finvdate 
from SalesDollars where finvdate <= '4/15/2014' and finvdate >= '01/15/2014'
order by finvdate
```

This is what I have so far what I need is to some how get this in after finvdate

```
select finvdate 
from SalesDollars where finvdate <= '1/16/2015' and finvdate >= '01/14/2014'
order by finvdate
```

Comment: You want to be able to query the `finvdate` column for two sets of date ranges?

Comment: I don't understand, can you show what you have now and what is the expected result ?

Comment: `get this in after finvdate`  is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that if I was to do a sub query it would look like the second select statement I have there. What I need to do is have five columns. The first one is company, the second customer number, the third total price, the forth is the date between 4/45/2014 and 01/15/2014, the fifth column is the one I don't know how to do I need the date between 1/16/2013 and 1/14/2014. With this query I will get back multiple rows so I cannot do a Sub query. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the business logic, use a TOP (1) order by UserDate on the sub-query to return one row.

The business logic is unclear.  Please give before and after data-sets and expected results to clarify the requirements.